# A confusing year to study

Tags: riddle, mathematics, english, science

I'm a teacher at an Academy. I set my students the task of writing a history essay on a year BCE. One of my students, instead of giving me his year, gave me this slip of paper before walking out the room:

> Hi, I am no longer needed at your academy. you're probably thinking 'He? well, 'E actually isn't needed'. and "'E" isn't needed, that isn't a Lie. i'm a humble Bea, A can be done without. No complaints, O time to leave. my Mug won't be seen with You anymore. oh, and my friend Ale, 'E isn't needed here either. like the number Pi when calculating one plus one, I am not needed. So my big O won't utter sound here again and shall be removed. Are, my other friend, 'E can go too. Cue for 'E and to disappear. take A away from our Bar. Rob, O no more left. Pod, O without it. A in our Pad isn't needed. Age is a 'E beyond his expiring date. i want a Cod, but i'm allergic to fish with O in their name. i'll just go Sob in a corner - O you've left. time for Tea, A can be done without.
>
> (+)

On the back of the paper appeared to be half the periodic table:

[image: Periodic table of Wikipedia. I take no claim for it as my own.]

> Which year BCE is my student doing his project on, or has he left forever?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code You might be able to get it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 481 BCE

- > 1 **H**: **H**i, I am no longer needed at your academy.
- > 1 **H**: you're probably thinking '**H**e? well, 'E actually isn't needed'.
- > 3 **Li**: and "'E" isn't needed, that isn't a **Li**e.
- > 4 **Be**: i'm a humble **Be**a, A can be done without.
- > 7 **N**: **N**o complaints, O time to leave.
- > 12 **Mg**: my **M**<del>u</del>**g** won't be seen with You anymore.
- > 13 **Al**: oh, and my friend **Al**e, 'E isn't needed here either.
- > 15 **P**: like the number **P**i when calculating one plus one, I am not needed.
- > 16 **S**: **S**o my big O won't utter sound here again and shall be removed.
- > 18 **Ar**: **Ar**e, my other friend, 'E can go too.
- > 29 **Cu**: **Cu**e for 'E and to disappear.
- > 35 **Br**: take A away from our **B**<del>a</del>**r**.
- > 37 **Rb**: **R**<del>o</del>**b**, O no more left.
- > 46 **Pd**: **P**<del>o</del>**d**, O without it.
- > 46 **Pd**: A in our **P**<del>a</del>**d** isn't needed.
- > 47 **Ag**: **Ag**e is a 'E beyond his expiring date.
- > 48 **Cd**: i want a **C**<del>o</del>**d**, but i'm allergic to fish with O in their name.
- > 51 **Sb**: i'll just go **S**<del>o</del>**b** in a corner - O you've left.
- > 52 **Te**: time for **Te**a, A can be done without.

So

> (+) yields 1+1+3+4+7+12+13+15+16+18+29+35+37+46+46+47+48+51+52 = 481 (BCE)

Comment: Seems like the next step would be to take each of those bullets and look up the corresponding number, right?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil True, another two are the same too

Comment: @JonathanAllan YOU'RE SO CLOSE! There is one thing left to do which can be found at the end of the letter. This will give you the year...

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil - You don't know Douglas Adams?

Comment: @JonathanAllan, yes with Hitchhikers guide to the galaxy - is this to do with 'the answer to life, the universe, and everything = 42?'

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil - yeah no worries LOL